# Trigonometry: Proving Question involving Sum to Product

Tags: trigonometry

I have a homework question that asks me to prove the following:
$$\frac{\sin \theta+\sin 7\theta}{\sin 3\theta+\sin 5\theta}=2\cos2\theta-1$$
When I tried proving it, I could only do
$$LHS=\frac{\sin \theta+\sin 7\theta}{\sin 3\theta+\sin 5\theta}$$
$$=\frac{2\sin4\theta\cos3\theta}{2\sin4\theta\cos\theta}$$
$$=\frac{\cos3\theta}{\cos\theta}$$

Is there a way to turn $\frac{\cos3\theta}{\cos\theta}$ into $2\cos2\theta-1$ or is there a different approach that I could take to the question? More importantly, I'd also like to know if I could simplify a cosine divided by a cosine like in this question here.

Edit: It's okay, I've found a solution that doesn't require the triple angle:

$$LHS=\frac{\cos3\theta}{\cos\theta}+1-1$$
$$=\frac{\cos3\theta+cos\theta}{\cos\theta}-1$$
$$=\frac{2cos2\theta cos\theta}{\cos\theta}-1$$
$$=2cos2\theta-1$$
$$=RHS$$

Thanks for all your help though guys.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\cos 3x}{\cos x} = \frac{4 \cos^3 x-2\cos x}{\cos x} = 4\cos^2 x-3= 2(2\cos^2 x-1)-1= 2\cos 2x-1$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos3\theta=4\cos^3\theta -3\cos\theta $

$\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$

Use this.